# Dropdown menu in Android (Xamarin C# or Java)

Tags: java, c#, xamarin.android

I am trying to achieve this design in android

[image: Dropdown in design]

I am actually working with Xamarin.Forms, but I haven't been able to find a cross-platform way to do this so I'm going with renderers. I figure, if I can find a solution for android (even in java), then I can port it to C# for Xamarin and use it in a renderer.

The problem now is I have no clue as to how to achieve this in native android either.

**More info**: The popup is meant to show when the filter icon is clicked.
The SearchView and the tabbedPage have been implemented already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SlideOverKit plugin where you can create a slide over popup from top and there you can implement your design. This is a cross platform plugin

[SlideOverKit](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit)

Complete details are available in the below link

[Details](https://www.xam-consulting.com/slideoverkit-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: I didn't want to have to use a plugin, but I will try it out. I might not have a choice.